# Use the OSX Lion Lock feature on a Macbook Air

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a similarly fast alternative to Crtl + Shift + Eject for new Macbook Air?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18365/is-there-a-similarly-fast-alternative-to-crtl-shift-eject-for-new-macbook-air)

Is there a way to use the new Lock feature of OSX Lion on a Macbook Air which does not come with an Eject key?

Comment: To which feature do you refer when you say "the new lock feature of OSX Lion"?

Comment: Read here http://osxdaily.com/2011/05/14/mac-os-x-lion-gets-new-lock-login-screens-with-ios-style-animations/

Answer (score 0):

You're not the first person to have this problem. The best workaround so far seems to involve Automator.
See: 
[Is there a similarly fast alternative to Crtl + Shift + Eject for new Macbook that lack eject keys?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18365/is-there-a-similarly-fast-alternative-to-crtl-shift-eject-for-new-macbook-air)