# How do I do control-shift-eject on a MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a similarly fast alternative to Crtl + Shift + Eject for new Macbook Air?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18365/is-there-a-similarly-fast-alternative-to-crtl-shift-eject-for-new-macbook-ai)

This keystroke turns off the display on most Macs.

But the Air does not have an eject key. How do I achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

see also: [Is there a similarly fast alternative to Crtl + Shift + Eject for new Macbook that lack eject keys?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18365/is-there-a-similarly-fast-alternative-to-crtl-shift-eject-for-new-macbook-ai)

Comment: For whatever it's worth, Control-shift-F12 (with or without the function key pressed) does not put my MBA display to sleep.

Comment: I've heard people say that before. I'm not sure why it works for some and not others. Odd.

Comment: I think with Mountain Lion it's Control-Shift-Power