# Manually lock screen

Tags: macbook-pro, screen-lock

I would like to lock the computer when not at home but leave the computer unlocked at home.

If I choose to lock the Mac after the screen saver starts I can lock it with <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>power</kbd> but then these settings will also force me to enter the password when I am home.

Is there a way to manually force a lock without locking the screen saver?

Comment: No duplicate because I am using power instead of eject. My problem is that using Ctrl+Shift+Power just seems to turn off the screen. But I want to lock it so a password is required to work at it again.

Comment: I quote one [answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/82361/9553) from that Q: "Require password immediately after sleep or screen saver begins should be checked in the Security & Privacy in System Preferences panel if you want to ensure a slept screen is also securely locked."

Comment: As written - the question is a duplicate. If you take the comments and explain how the other question doesn't work (linking to it in the body) we can then re-open this. Just explain how you don't get how the answers on the other questions would work after reading Arne's comment.

Comment: @bmike he commented my answer: he knows about the key combination, he wants to know how to lock the screen without using the screen saver.

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/lock-me-now/id464265594?mt=12 <-- press command + L to lock or set your own command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to reduce the time for a password prompt after the screen saver starts you can use *Keychain Access*. Start it and in the preferences choose to show the status in the menu bar

[image]

You will be then able to lock the screen immediately with *Lock Screen*:

[image]

Comment: Confirmed that if the security option is set to require password immediately, then Control+Shift+Power will lock the Macbook.

Comment: Is there a way to leave this disabled and still lock the screen somehow?

Comment: @urbaindepuce I don't understand what do you want to achieve. The setting does what you asked. Why do you want it disabled?

Comment: I think there are 3rd party apps that can do this. In one of the other questions [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com) is mentioned. YMMV

Comment: @Matteo I don't want that my screen is automatically locked when I am at home. When I am using the computer at work or school I want to be able to lock it when leaving it. When enabling that setting I always have to supply my password when leaving and returning to my computer at home. And I don't want to set it everytime when goint to work or school or returning home.

Comment: @urbaindepuce I updated the answer

Comment: @urbaindepuce I tried to rewrite your question to make it more clear (according to your comment). You should now try to re-open it as it clearly is not a duplicate of the referenced question