# How to turn off your MacBook Pro 2016 with Touch Bar via keyboard shortcut

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, shortcut, touch-bar

Since my new MacBook Pro 2016 with Touch Bar I'm unable to turn off my MacBook using the keyboard <kbd>CNTR</kbd><kbd>OPTION</kbd><kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd>. I saw this question about the screen lock: [Simular question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/261496/how-to-turnoff-screen-lock-macbook-pro-with-touch-bar-using-keyboard#new-answer?newreg=21f0dda509024137bc89bd0e6aa5b52d) but there is no button in the Touch bar for turning off the Mac completely. Is there a new keyboard shortcut for this?

These are the only options to drag into the Touch Bar:
[image]

Comment: Doesn't the Touch ID sensor button function as the power key?

Comment: Nop that was my first try.

Comment: Worth a try: BetterTouchTools. You can easily set up a shortcut for this. Also has many more features if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut you refer to was actually only one of two keyboard shortcuts that worked the same way. The other one was to use <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd> and the <kbd>Eject</kbd> key instead of the <kbd>Power</kbd> button.

Regardless, both of these keyboard shortcut combinations will quit all apps and shut down your Mac. Of course, if you have any open documents that have not been saved you'll be asked whether you want to save them.

Since you have a Touch Bar model, I suspect you will just need to ensure you're in the right interface to see the <kbd>Eject</kbd> key option.

Otherwise, what actually happens if you still use the <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd> and the <kbd>Power</kbd> combination, remembering that in your case the Touch ID doubles up as your <kbd>Power</kbd> button?

If there is no way to get that to work, you could add your own custom keyboard shortcut to achieve what you want, but that will mean changing some of the other Function Key behaviours - if this is an acceptable option and you need assistance to do this, let me know and I'll update this answer.

**[UPDATE]**

As requested via comments, here are the steps to creating a custom keyboard shortcut using one of your Function keys to replicate the <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Power</kbd> button combination:

1. Go to **System Preferences**
2. Select the **Keyboard** option
3. Ensure you are on the *Keyboard* tab
4. Make sure that the *Use all F1,F2, etc. keys as standard function keys* is **not** ticked
5. Now choose the **Shortcuts** tab
6. Select **App Shortcuts** in the lefthand column
7. Click "**+**" symbol at the bottom of the right pane
8. Leave the Application drop-down as *All Applications*
9. In the Menu Title field type this in exactly: **Shut Down...**
10. In the Keyboard shortcut field press the <kbd>fn</kbd> and <kbd>F1</kbd> keys
11. Click on **Add**
12. Exit System Preferences

Now you should be able to just press the <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> key combination to shutdown your MBP.

**NOTE:** The reason at Step 4 I wanted you to ensure that the *Use all F1,F2, etc. keys as standard function keys* is **not** ticked was because you wanted to set the keyboard shortcut on a key that is already used for something else. However, if you do want to leave *Use all F1,F2, etc. keys as standard function keys* ticked, you can change the original <kbd>F1</kbd> key shortcut to something else first and then set the <kbd>F1</kbd> key (without the need for the <kbd>fn</kbd> key) as your keyboard shortcut.

Any questions, just ask.

Comment: The Eject button is no part of the Touch Bar button options (see my post with a screenshot with possible options)

Comment: Just added a couple of paragraphs to my answer - does this help at all?

Comment: The touchID / power button doesn't work with this shortkey, please let me know how to make my own shortkey for this.
The eject button is maybe visible when I install the portable DVD drive. But this is no option

Comment: Okay, in that case are there any Function Keys you currently use that you don't want changed? Or, more to the point, what Function Key would you be happy to change to become your new _Quit all apps and shutdown_ key? Or are you happy for me to just pick one of the lesser used ones for you?

Comment: F1 would be great

Comment: Just added the instructions you requested. Let me know how you go.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across the same problem: not finding the power button to force a shut down. I found *the power button actually is still there* and [coincides with the TouchId button at the extreme right of the touch bar](https://blog.macsales.com/42219-tech-tip-how-to-force-quit-a-macbook-pro-with-touch-bar). No need to go through these edits of the fn keys.

Comment: That one is only for turning on and force shutting down. I wanted to use it with the key combination like older macs to turn it normally down and close all open apps all at once.
I’ve add a custom short key alt cmd cntr + \
So instead of on/off key I use now the back-slash.